# Strip debug info from linux shared library

Tags: linux, gcc, debug-symbols

I’m using GCC to compile a shared library for ARM Linux. Here’s my compiler options from CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_definitions( "-std=c++14 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wall -Wno-psabi -march=native -mfpu=neon" )
```

I’ve just opened the resulting .so file in a disassembler. I was disappointed to see a lot of stuff there. It showed me names for everything, including all my internal classes, and functions that were never exported. Even the stuff from anonymous namespaces is still there. On the “Exports” tab on the disassembler, I only see a dozen of functions I actually export (plus just a few extra: `.init_proc` `.term_proc` `_edata` `__bss_end__` and `call_weak_fn`).

On Windows, I only see these things if I have a PDB file for the module I’m disassembling. But I don’t ship my .PDB files.

I’d like the same behavior for GCC.

Is there a way to tell GCC to stop including that debug info (=the mangled name of each and every function) in the .so file, and actually compile these things into binary addresses?

Comment: Another option to help keep ELF section size smaller is `-Wl,-exclude-libs,All` (see [`ld(1)` linker options](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ld)). It stops your shared object from re-exporting stuff from its dependencies.

Comment: *"It showed me names for everything, including all my internal classes, and functions that were never exported...."* - Two things may help. First, compile with `-ffunction-sections -fdata-sections`, and link with `-Wl,--gc-sections`. Second, you can strip symbols after linking. For that, use something like `arm-linux-androideabi-strip --strip-all foo`.

Comment: *"Is there a way to tell GCC to stop including that debug info..."* - They are already compiled into binary. What you are seeing is the debug record to help with debugging and diagnostics. Usually you either (1) omit debug symbols; or (2) you strip after building. That's the Unix and Linux way. Also see the [`strip(1)` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/strip)

Comment: Added these compiler + linker options to CMakeLists.txt (using add_definitions and target_link_libraries), that changed nothing.

Comment: Yeah, just discovered /usr/bin/strip, it did what I want and reduced size to 55% of the original. Ideally I’d like the cmake to do that, however I’m OK using a separate post-build step (I’m using a shell script to invoke cmake anyway).

Comment: Related, it looks like you are missing some options and flags normally used by the NDK. I've got a list of them cribbed away at [Android | NDK CXXFLAGS](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Android_(Command_Line)#NDK_CXXFLAGS). You will definitely want to use `-DANDROID`, `-msoft-float` or `-mfloat-abi=softfp`, `-frtti` and `-fexceptions` to ensure C++ expcetions pass correctly through C code. Cmake fails to add them even though some are platform requirements. If you don't use soft floats then you will see some strange floating point behavior.

Comment: When linking the with gcc, there's `-s` switch to strip the symbols. I've only used it with executables, however -- I'm not sure it works with shared objects.

Comment: @jww thanks but I’m not building for Android. That’s for another ARM Linux, Debian, Rockchip, etc..

Comment: @KevinBoone Yeah, tried `-s` first, no effect. Probably doesn't work for shared libraries.

Comment: Odd -- it works for me: I just tried it. If I link a .so like this: `gcc -s --shared -o test.so -Wl,-soname,test.so -Wl,--whole-archive test.o -Wl,--no-whole-archive` then it's about 40% smaller with the `-s` than without it, and `file test.so` says it's stripped. I suppose there could be a bunch of other factors in play, however.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `-Wl,--strip-debug` to your linker flags.

Answer (score 0):

I am dealing with a similar problem and for me using

```
$ arm-none-eabi-objcopy --strip-unneeded -O ihex firmware.elf firmware.hex
```

worked just like doing

```
$ arm-none-eabi-strip firmware.elf
$ arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O ihex firmware.elf firmware.hex
```

from the [docs](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/binutils-arm-none-eabi/arm-none-eabi-objcopy.1.en.html):

> --strip-unneeded
>
> Remove all symbols that are not needed for relocation processing in addition to debugging symbols and sections stripped by --strip-debug.

and you can easily put that in your makefile.
This works for me cause I use the hex file to flash my device, if you use the .elf that is not going to help you.